# Why does signing on to one site not sign me on to all of them?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, login

I've seen this question asked 3 times, but in none of those threads did I find a satisfactory answer.  I'm not asking about reputation: it makes sense that different sites should have different reputations.  However, consider the StackExchange drop-down menu at the top left of the screen.  When looking through the "Hot questions", the links are often to sister websites of StackExchange (programmers.stackexchange i.e.).  It doesn't make sense to me that if I go to one of those sister sites, I'm no longer logged in.  I feel like it's counterintuitive to click a link to go answer a question, only to find that you can't answer that question until you log in.

What is the reason for this?  Is there an option to do as I'm suggesting?

Comment: In theory, it should happen. Although there might be reasons it doesn't. Have a look at this blog post for more info http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/